# Guice: using Injector?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have one Maven module where I define some utils shared across several other Maven modules.
In this module I want to create some singleton:

```
package org.me.util;

public interface Baz {
    String myMethod(String s);
}

@Singleton
public class Foo implements Baz {
private Bar bar;

    @Inject
    Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public String myMethod(String s) {
        return s;
    }

}
```

Then I bind my interface with:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Baz.class).to(Foo.class);
    }

}
```

Suppose I want to use this singleton from another Maven module (say, a web service), how do I achieve this?
The only way I found was to create a class in my util Maven module like:

```
package org.me.util;
public class Main {

    private static Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());;

    public static Injector getInjector() {
        return injector;
    }
```

Alternatively I could create the injector in a static main method as seen in the Guice tutorials, and save an instance somewhere.

Then from my web service do something like:

```
Baz baz = Main.getInjector().getInstance(Baz.class);
```

But this does not seem very elegant because I have to pass my injector around (in this case by providing it with a static getter).

Is there any other way? Thanks.

Comment: Ideally you'd also inject whatever is in the other module. Can you `@Inject Baz baz` and then get an instance of whatever needs `Baz` from the injector?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. I am doing my first steps with Guice and DI. But isn't it bad practice to inject fields like @Inject Baz baz?  Anyway I don't understand how am I supposed to get an instance of my singleton without using the injector.

Comment: Right - you could also inject into the constructor of your other class. All I'm saying is that you should `@Inject` your singleton where you need it, if possible. Guice can only help you if it's creating the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more elegant way to pass the `Baz` object it's to inject it.

For example,

```
 public class BusinessService {
     private final Baz baz;
     @Inject
     public BusinessService(Baz baz) { this.baz = baz; }
 }
```

And again if you want to use the BusinessService in a WS.

```
 public class WebService {
     private final BusinessService businessService;
     @Inject
     public WebService(BusinessService businessService) { this.businessService = businessService; }
 }
```

By doing this, all the dependency are clearly exposed in the API signatures.

---

The remaining problem is that you have to create the Injector in the entry point of an application.

In a standalone application, the injector is usually created in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new UtilModule(), new BusinessModule());
     BusinessService businessService = injector.getInstance(BusinessService.class);
     ...

}
```

In a web application, the injector might be created in different way. It depends of the framework.

Servlets:

- [guice servlet module](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ServletModule)

[Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.io/):

- [dropwizard-guice](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice)
- [dropwizard-guicey](https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey)

[playframework](https://www.playframework.com)

- [play-module](https://www.playframework.com/modules/guice-1.0/home)

...